# Why don't you have to dereference a pointer using strcpy and strlen?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I've been trying to create my own string class, but I ran into a problem with the following code below:

```
String::String(const char *s) : str {nullptr}
{
    if(s == nullptr)
    {
        str = new char[1];
        *str = '\0';
    }else{
        str = new char[std::strlen(*s)+1];
        strcpy(*str,*s);
    }
}
```

What I passed into the constructor is a const char pointer; to get to the value inside the pointer I have to dereference it right? But why don't you have to dereference the pointer when putting arguments into strcpy and strlen?

Shown below.

```
String::String(const char *s) : str {nullptr}
{
    if(s == nullptr)
    {
        str = new char[1];
        *str = '\0';
    }else{
        str = new char[std::strlen(s)+1];
        strcpy(str,s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::strlen` doesn't take "the value inside the pointer". It takes a pointer. For the same reason your `String` constructor takes a pointer.

Comment: Look at the signature for `strlen`. It takes a `const char*`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen It takes a `const char*` because that's how it's designed.

Comment: Dereferencing a `const char *` would yield a `char`, which isn't useful if you want to do something with an entire string and not just that single character.

Comment: Could you tell how long a string is by looking at its first character, or which novel I'm thinking of that starts with `'G'`?

Comment: Since you are interested in re-creating parts of the standard library (a useful exercise), would you consider writing your own versions of `strlen` and `strcpy`? That might lead to understanding.

Comment: All you are doing is passing the received pointer to `strlen()` and `strcpy()`.   Those functions dereference the pointers they receive, just as your code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `strcpy` and `strlen` have `char *` as parameters therefore you would not need to deference.

More information:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> str = new char[std::strlen(*s)+1];
> ```
>
> what I passed into the function is a const pointer

No, that's not what you passed. What you passed into the function is a `char`. `char` is not a pointer.

> to get to the value inside the pointer I have to dereference it right?

When you have a pointer to `char`, then to get the pointed `char` you do have to indirect through the pointer. But `std::strlen` does not expect a `char` as an argument, so a `char` is not what you need and thus you don't need to indirect through the pointer which would get you a `char`.

The argument of `std::strlen` is a pointer to `char`. So, if you have a pointer to `char`, and you need to pass a pointer to `char` into the function, then what do you need to do to your pointer to `char` in order to get a pointer to `char` that could be passed into the function? You need to do nothing, because you already have a pointer to `char` which is what you can pass into the function (assuming the value satisfies the pre-conditions of the function).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass address of string's beginning, and string is essentially a sequence of non-zero bytes. A simplest `strlen` looks like:

```
size_t strlen(const char* s)
{
    const char* p = s;
    
    while(*p) p++;
    return p - s;
}
```

Real implementations usually do some optimization by checking long words  and/or using direct assembler code which results in better performance than scanning memory byte by byte. Without knowing the address of character, it cannot be done, especially in C where references didn't exist.